# Is it possible to have common entities for both Cassandra(NoSQL) and mysql(RDBMS)

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-data, cassandra-2.0, nosql

We would like to support two databases MySQL and Cassandra to our application. Our application will be built using Spring. I would to like to have common entities which has to be shared by both MySQL and Cassandra  I would like to change the DB dynamically based on customer preference. How can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements to have the system runnable on both data stores, with only one at a time, this I think it is achievable.

The following advices i believe will let you achieve this but i didn't try'em: (supposing that you uses spring-boot)

1. In maven put the dependency for spring data jpa and spring data mongo.
2. Enable both jpa and mongo repositories (see EnableJpaRepositoies)
3. On entities put both JPA and Mongo annotations.
4. Use PagingAndSortingRepository as base interface for you repositories
5. In application.properties **either** configure mysql or mongo db through spring boot well-defined properties

This might work in regular spring apps but will need modifications; also include corresponding driver dependencies in pom file.

Edit: you can use 'spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=false' ( and its mongo counterpart) source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.java